# Custom domain does not redirect to my heroku app

Tags: heroku, domain-name

Last week, I delete and re-create my heroku instance (I now use Europe instance).
After this change, my domain name fail, I try to simplify the config (inspired by this [blog post](http://www.leemunroe.com/io-domains-heroku), but it still failing.

My domain name is registered on Gandi. There my config :

```
@ 10800 IN A 174.129.212.2
@ 10800 IN A 75.101.145.87
@ 10800 IN A 75.101.163.44
www 10800 IN CNAME dartf.herokuapp.com
```

And Heroku domain name setting :

```
dartf.herokuapp.com
dar.tf
www.dar.tf
```

dartf.herokuapp.com is ok but, not my domain name :
2 problems :

- dar.tf says the heroku app does not exist
- www.dar.tf says the domain name is unknow

Does anybody know what is wrong  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use IP addresses on Heroku anymore, certainly never in the Europe region. You need to use a CNAME to dartf.herokuapp.com - if you use something like DNSSimple for DNS management you can use an ALIAS record which will let you do this for your dar.tf domain.